# Compare multiple records fetch the top 1 record based on filter conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

My Table is as follows,

```
   UserID    PreSalary    ExpSalary    TotalExp    NoticePeriod
     1         1000         2500          2             30
     2         1700         5000          2.6           60
     3         8200         10000         5.9           15
     4         3000.5       6000.75       4             20
```

I Wanna Compare All the rows with the first Record and Fetch top 1 Record which has  values nearest to the first record.

I am using Sql Server 2008 Edition and my query attempt was,

```
    Select  * from #tbl GROUP by UserID ,PreSalary ,ExpSalary ,TotalExp,NoticePeriod Having (MAX(TotalExp) = (Select top 2 TotalExp from #tbl  ) ,MIN(PreSalary) = (Select top 2 PreSalary from #tbl)  )
```

The expected output is

```
   UserID    PreSalary    ExpSalary    TotalExp    NoticePeriod
    2          8200        10000          5.9           15
```

**Explanation:**
Comparing last 3 rows of PreSalary UserId 2 wins , 
Comparing last 3 rows of ExpSalary UserId 2 wins ,
Comparing last 3 rows of TotalExp  UserId 3 wins ,
Comparing last 3 rows of NoticePeriod UserId 3 wins

If a tie happens  between two UserIDs , Then  TotalExp and NoticePeriod is given Priority.
So USerID 3 wins

Any Help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Comment: Based upon the above data, what is you expected output?

Comment: Why compare with the last 3 rows?

Comment: Hi Felix Pamittan , I keep the First record as my base record  and find the best among  other records  in the table which has the column  values  nearest to the base record

Comment: Your explanation and expected output is contradicting. Your expected output shows `UserID = 2` while your explanation says `UserId = 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `RANK`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8125f1/1/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT t.*,
        rn1 = RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t.PreSalary - x.PreSalary),
        rn2 = RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t.ExpSalary - x.ExpSalary),
        rn3 = RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t.TotalExp - x.TotalExp DESC),
        rn4 = RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t.NoticePeriod - x.NoticePeriod)
    FROM tbl t
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT TOP 1
            PreSalary, ExpSalary, TotalExp, NoticePeriod
        FROM tbl
        ORDER BY UserID
    )x
    WHERE UserID <>(SELECT TOP 1 UserID FROM tbl ORDER BY UserID)
)
SELECT TOP 1
    UserId, PreSalary, ExpSalary, TotalExp, NoticePeriod
FROM Cte 
ORDER BY 
    rn1 + rn2 + rn3 + rn4,
    rn3,
    rn4
```

---

```
SELECT TOP 1 UserID FROM tbl ORDER BY UserID
```

The above will return your base record. The idea is to rank each row (except for the base) relative to the base record. This is done using `RANK`.

On the final `SELECT`, the priority will be based on the overall ranking, thus `rn1 + rn2 + rn3 + rn4`. Should there be a tie, order by `rn3` and `rn4`, the `TotalExp` and `NoticePeriod` respectively.

---

RESULT

```
| UserId | PreSalary | ExpSalary | TotalExp | NoticePeriod |
|--------|-----------|-----------|----------|--------------|
|      3 |      8200 |     10000 |      5.9 |           15 |
```